# Thunar 1.8.14 - change drag and drop behaviour

Tags: customization, thunar

I've just noticed that Thunar on my pc COPIES files when they are dragged and dropped into another folder, rather than MOVING them.

There is another answer to this question saying Thunar can MOVE files by dragging and dropping with the right mouse button. But I'd be grateful to know if it's possible to change the behaviour for dragging and dropping with the left mouse button from COPY to MOVE?

thanks,
Catty

Comment: Just for your information: The drag/drop operation performs a move when the source and target folders are on the same partition but it results in a copy when the source and target are on different partitions. [Source](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/working-with-files-and-folders).

Comment: hi thanks for this - on network drives it's doing it on the same partition - is that something I have misconfigured or should I have mentioned that was part of the scope?